# failed linking references

Tags: android-studio, xml

El problema que tengo es que a la hora de crear un estilo nuevo en el documento style.xml, el nombre sale en rojo y no se puede compilar el codigo correctamente. Codigo de error:

```
Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\kennedy\Documents\StudioProjects\Musicae\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1461: error: style attribute 'attr/primaryDark (aka com.example.musicae:attr/primaryDark)' not found.
C:\Users\kennedy\Documents\StudioProjects\Musicae\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1462: error: style attribute 'attr/secondaryDark (aka com.example.musicae:attr/secondaryDark)' not found.
error: failed linking references.
```

Este es mi codigo de mi style.xml y a continuación el de color.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<!-- Main color theme  -->
<style name="LogginView" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="primaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="secondaryDark">@color/secondaryDark</item>
</style>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
    <color name="primaryDark">#2F3136</color>
    <color name="secondaryDark">#36393F</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que cada item de tu estilo debe ser un nombre ya predefinido de un estilo.

En el demo que pones no existe primaryDark como attributo de propiedad válido

entonces para que funcione tu estilo debe quedar así

```
<!-- Main color theme  -->
<style name="LogginView" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/secondaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Más información detallada

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes

Answer (score 1):

Veo que realizaste los cambios pero el error menciona que los archivos aun tienen problema, si notas en realidad estos son los archivos generados y no son los que modificaste ya que se encuentran en `build\intermediates\`

```
C:\Users\kennedy\Documents\StudioProjects\Musicae\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1461: error: style attribute 'attr/primaryDark (aka com.example.musicae:attr/primaryDark)' not found.
C:\Users\kennedy\Documents\StudioProjects\Musicae\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1462: error: style attribute 'attr/secondaryDark (aka com.example.musicae:attr/secondaryDark)' not found.
```

Recuerda que los estilos deben agregarse dentro del archivo styles.xml y no dentro de `values.xml`

y cambia los elementos en tu archivo ya que no son validos los siguientes atributos:

```
<item name="primaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
<item name="secondaryDark">@color/secondaryDark</item>
```

puedes usar:

```
   <item name="colorPrimary">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">
    <item name="colorAccent">
```

Este sería un ejemplo

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<!-- Main color theme  -->
<style name="LogginView" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/secondaryDark</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

---

Construye nuevamente tu proyecto, si un simple `Build` > `Clean Project` no funciona, te sugiero eliminar los directorios `/build` de tu proyecto y volver a construirlo.